# Jmeter: While controller didn't break when conditon is met

Tags: jmeter

I have a sampler within a thread group that need to be executed  until it  get a status code = 200
If first run is successfull (status code =200) should have only one execution of the sampler else if fail, repeat until status code =200. The sampler execution (status code=200) didn’t stop  despite the condition in the while controller. Where am I wrong.

I tried the following:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/guFti.png)

while controller -
{__javaScript("${response}"!="200")}

Jsr223 listener -

```
String ResponseCode = sampleResult.getResponseCode();
vars.put("response",ResponseCode);
```

Comment: Did you try `${__groovy(${response} != "200")}`?, and `String ResponseCode = prev.getResponseCode();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Correct [__javaScript() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__javaScript) syntax would be:

```
${__javaScript("${response}" != "200",)}
```

[While Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#While_Controller)'s documentation suggests using [__jexl3()](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__jexl3) or [__groovy()](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy) functions so consider migrating.

- jexl3: `${__jexl3("${response}" != "200",)}`
- groovy: `${__groovy(vars.get('response') != "200",)}`